# How can i show label text in front of image?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

Code is below, my main goal is when i push the learn button-as you see in the images-, after select a method, to show texts and images about the selected method. But when i switch to Polynomial Regression Page from Logistic Regression page, the images areas on the Logistic Regression page, hide the other page's texts. I have used labelimage1.place_forget() but it didn't work. I need to show texts in front of the images when i switch the pages.

Images :

[LogisticRegressionPage](https://ibb.co/MNmp4tx)

[PolynomialRegressionPage](https://ibb.co/2dt0rYC)

[PolynomialPageAfterLogisticRegression](https://ibb.co/XJbqK21)

Code is :

```
def HelpLogisticRegression():

trainlabel.config(font=("Times New Roman",9),text=("""To deal with outliers, Logistic Regression uses Sigmoid function.An explanation of logistic regression can begin with an explanation of the standard logistic function. The logistic function is a Sigmoid function, which takes any real value between zero and one. It is defined as"""))
trainlabel.place(x=180,
               y=35)

path1 = "lr1.png"
image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path1))
imagelabel1 = Label(helpml4, image = image1)
imagelabel1.place(x=275,y=130)
imagelabel1.config(bg="white")

trainlabel2.config(font=("Times New Roman",9),text=("And if we plot it, the graph will be S curve,"))
trainlabel2.place(x=180,
                   y=180)
path2 = "lr2.png"
image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path2))
imagelabel2 = Label(helpml4, image = image2)
imagelabel2.place(x=200,y=220)
imagelabel2.config(bg="white")
#    
trainlabel3.config(font=("Times New Roman",9),text="Let’s consider t as linear function in a univariate regression model.")
trainlabel3.place(x=180,
                   y=500)

path3 = "lr3.png"
image3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path3))
imagelabel3 = Label(helpml4, image = image3)
imagelabel3.place(x=275,y=530)
imagelabel3.config(bg="white")


trainlabel4.config(font=("Times New Roman",9),text="So the Logistic Equation will become")
trainlabel4.place(x=685,
                   y=35)

path4 = "lr4.png"
image4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path4))
imagelabel4 = Label(helpml4, image = image4)
imagelabel4.place(x=785,y=55)
imagelabel4.config(bg="white")


trainlabel5.config(font=("Times New Roman",9),text="Now, when logistic regression model come across an outlier, it will take care of it.")
trainlabel5.place(x=685,
                   y=150)

path5 = "lr6.png"
image5 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path5))
imagelabel5 = Label(helpml4, image = image5)
imagelabel5.place(x=600,y=180)
imagelabel5.config(bg="white")

trainlabel6.config(font=("Times New Roman",9),text="But sometime it will shift its y axis to left or right depending on outliers positions.")
trainlabel6.place(x=685,y=400)
# To show images it is required.

imagelabel1.configure(image=imagelabel1)

#   
def HelpPolynomialLinearRegression():
trainlabel.config(font=("Times New Roman",9),text=("""In statistics, polynomial regression is a form of regression analysis in which the relationship between the independent variable x and the dependent variable y is modelled as an nth degree polynomial in x. Polynomial regression fits a nonlinear relationship between the value of x and the corresponding conditional mean of y, denoted E(y |x), and has been used to describe nonlinear phenomena such as the growth rate of tissues, the distribution of carbon isotopes in lake sediments, and the progression of disease epidemics. Although polynomial regression fits a nonlinear model to the data, as a statistical estimation problem it is linear, in the sense that the regression function E(y | x) is linear in the unknown parameters that are estimated from the data. For this reason, polynomial regression is considered to be a special case of multiple linear regression.The explanatory (independent) variables resulting from the polynomial expansion of the “baseline” variables are known as higher-degree terms. Such variables are also used in classification settings.Notice that PR is very similar to MLR, but consider at the same time instead of the different variables the same one X1, but in different powers; so basically we are using 1 variable to different powers of the same original variable."""))
trainlabel.place(x=180,
               y=35)

trainlabel2.config(font=("Times New Roman",9),text=(""))
trainlabel2.place(x=180,
                   y=430)
trainlabel3.config(font=("Times New Roman",9),text="")
trainlabel3.place(x=685,
                   y=35)


trainlabel4.config(font=("Times New Roman",9),text="")
trainlabel4.place(x=685,
                   y=95)


trainlabel5.config(font=("Times New Roman",9),text="")
trainlabel5.place(x=685,
                   y=390)
trainlabel6.config(text="")
# To show images it is required.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the question like this, i add top of the define section global so i defined all of the imagelabels after that i destroy all the imagelabels if it is defined because i can't know the page has images or not so i've written try and except concept after all i added imagelabel1.configure(image=imagelabel1)

```
def HelpLogisticRegression():
global imagelabel1,imagelabel2,imagelabel3,imagelabel4,imagelabel5,imagelabel6
try: imagelabel1.destroy()
except:print("Can't destroy 1")
try: imagelabel2.destroy()
except:print("Can't destroy 2")
try: imagelabel3.destroy()
except:print("Can't destroy 3")
try: imagelabel4.destroy()
except:print("Can't destroy 4")
try: imagelabel5.destroy()
except:print("Can't destroy 5")
try: imagelabel6.destroy()
except:print("Can't destroy 6")

trainlabel.config(font=("Times New Roman",9),text=("""To deal with outliers, Logistic Regression uses Sigmoid function.An explanation of logistic regression can begin with an explanation of the standard logistic function. The logistic function is a Sigmoid function, which takes any real value between zero and one. It is defined as"""))
trainlabel.place(x=180,
               y=35)

path1 = "lr1.png"
image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path1))
imagelabel1 = Label(helpframe, image = image1)
imagelabel1.place(x=275,y=130)
imagelabel1.config(bg="white")

trainlabel2.config(font=("Times New Roman",9),text=("And if we plot it, the graph will be S curve,"))
trainlabel2.place(x=180,
                   y=180)
path2 = "lr2.png"
image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path2))
imagelabel2 = Label(helpframe, image = image2)
imagelabel2.place(x=200,y=220)
imagelabel2.config(bg="white")
#    
trainlabel3.config(font=("Times New Roman",9),text="Let’s consider t as linear function in a univariate regression model.")
trainlabel3.place(x=180,
                   y=500)

path3 = "lr3.png"
image3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path3))
imagelabel3 = Label(helpframe, image = image3)
imagelabel3.place(x=275,y=530)
imagelabel3.config(bg="white")


trainlabel4.config(font=("Times New Roman",9),text="So the Logistic Equation will become")
trainlabel4.place(x=685,
                   y=35)

path4 = "lr4.png"
image4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path4))
imagelabel4 = Label(helpframe, image = image4)
imagelabel4.place(x=785,y=55)
imagelabel4.config(bg="white")


trainlabel5.config(font=("Times New Roman",9),text="Now, when logistic regression model come across an outlier, it will take care of it.")
trainlabel5.place(x=685,
                   y=150)

path5 = "lr6.png"
image5 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path5))
imagelabel5 = Label(helpframe, image = image5)
imagelabel5.place(x=600,y=180)
imagelabel5.config(bg="white")

trainlabel6.config(font=("Times New Roman",9),text="But sometime it will shift its y axis to left or right depending on outliers positions.")
trainlabel6.place(x=685,y=400)
# To show images it is required.

imagelabel1.configure(image=imagelabel1)
imagelabel2.configure(image=imagelabel2)
imagelabel3.configure(image=imagelabel3)
imagelabel4.configure(image=imagelabel4)
imagelabel5.configure(image=imagelabel5)
```